# Vue.js weird thing with window property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I init my vue.js 2.0 app I make `window.User` object.

That's all going well. Then in some components I'm using it in my 
templates:

```
v-if="this.User.role == 2"
```

So in some component's this is working and in some not -_- (`Cannot read property 'role' of undefined`). How is that even possible? In the component's where this is not working I've tried this:

```
created() {
    alert(window.User.role);
}
```

And the proper result shows up! But in the template it's not working. What could be going on here. Very very frustrating thing.

In my **bootstrap.js**:

```
window.User = Laravel.user;
```

I register all my components the same way:

```
Vue.component('corporations',           require('./components/corporation/Corporations.vue'));
```

Comment: Post the whole code please.

Comment: You should also set User to data property.
`created() {
  this.User = window.User
}`

Comment: @SrinivasDamam but then I've to do that for every component?

Comment: You can use Mixins for this.But I would recommend Vuex.
`var UserMixin = {
  created: function () {
    this.User = window.User
  },
}`
// component that uses this mixin
// import your mixin here
`export default {
 mixins: [UserMixin]
} `

Comment: `this` into vue instance is binded to vue instance itself not on a window.So use this `v-if="window.User.role == 2"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `User` is acting like a global variable that you want access to in all components and you want it to be reactive, you can add it to the root Vue's data and then refer to it everywhere else as `this.$root.User`.

You can also use a mixin to declare a `computed` that makes it available on all components that use the mixin. Like this:

```
var mixin = {
    computed: {
        User: function () { return window.User; }
    }
}
```

The mixin is probably a better route to go.

Comment: so how do I add it to the root vue js data? where? in app.js? in a component? just in app.js `this.$root.User = {}`? how can I import the mixin? if i define the mixin globally, doesnt seem to become available.